# Clear Dell OpenManage SBE memory log of all and specific connectors without rebooting the server

Tags: linux, dell-openmanage

Running `omreport chassis` results in:

```
Health

Main System Chassis

SEVERITY : COMPONENT
Ok       : Fans
Ok       : Intrusion
Critical : Memory
Ok       : Power Management
Ok       : Processors
Ok       : Temperatures
Ok       : Voltages
Ok       : Hardware Log
Ok       : Batteries

For further help, type the command followed by -?
```

Running `dcicfg command=clearmemfailures` in order to clear the SBE fails:

```
Clearing failures using mask: 31
DIMM_X1 : failed status: 270
```

Based on this message the assumption was that the command should be issued on the memory that is causing the issue.

Consulting the help by executing `dcicfg command=clearmemfailures -?` resulted in:

```
Dell(R) Data Engine Data Engine Configuration Utility  7.4.0 (BLD_1)
Copyright (C) Dell Inc. 1995-2013

Usage: dcicfg command=COMMAND [PARAMETERS...] [OPTIONS...]

COMMAND:
  clearmemfailures    Clear memory device failure mode

PARAMETERS:
  listonly=BOOLN      (opt.) list all occupied memory connectors
  connectors=STRING   (opt.) memory device connector name (default=all)
  failures=STRING     (opt.) failure type to clear (default=all)
```

Running `omreport chassis memory` indicates which memory is causing the issue:

```
Index          : 3
Status         : Critical
Connector Name : DIMM_Y1
Type           : DDRY - Synchronous Unregistered (Unbuffered)
Size           : Y  MB
```

and issuing `dcicfg command=clearmemfailures connectors=DIMM_Y1` indicated that the memory connector cannot be found:

```
Clearing failures using mask: 31
failed to find any memory connector based on the names provided
```

`omreport chassis memory index=3` indicates that the memory has thrown SBEs:

```
Memory Device Information

Health : Critical

Status      : Critical
Device Name : DIMM_Y1
Size        : Y MB
Type        : DDRY Synchronous Unregistered (Unbuffered)
Speed       : Y ns
Rank        : Dual
Failures    : Single-bit warning error rate exceeded.
              Single-bit failure error rate exceeded.
```

**Questions**

1. What does the failed status `270` mean?
2. Why can the memory connector not be found while it has been specified and it exists?
3. How to clear SBEs?

**Attempts to solve the issue**

The following commands from [this Q&A](https://serverfault.com/questions/536636/multibit-error-encountered-on-dell-server-memory):

1. sudo omconfig system esmlog action=clear
2. sudo omconfig system alertlog action=clear

were issued to clear the SBE, but the `Critical` memory status persists.

Comment: I encoutered the same error when I tried to run dcicfg as a user that has not enough rights. When I run it as root, the error 270 goes away.

Comment: @Gérard Thank you. Now it works. Please post this comment as an answer as it answers the question and remove the comment. I will accept and upvote the answer and then the solution is clear for other users that experience the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had trouble clearing the SBE log using `dcicfg`.  The below steps worked for me:

Download the [Dell Support Live Image](http://www.dell.com/support/contents/us/en/19/article/Product-Support/Self-support-Knowledgebase/enterprise-resource-center/Enterprise-Tools/support-live-image) (download link at bottom of this link)

1. Boot the system using the "DOS-Based Diagnostic Tools (Dell 9G-10G servers)" or "DOS-Based Diagnostic Tools (Dell 11G servers)" option. The Customer Diagnostic Menu Ver 1.6 is displayed.
2. When the Enter option or letter is displayed, then press the <4> key. The MS-DOS prompt is displayed.
3. Type C:, and then press < Enter >. The current drive changes to C:.
4. Type "mpmemory –ptech -tlogclr", and then press < Enter >.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer. The aim is to avoid rebooting the system as it is a Production server. Is it also possible to clear the memory log without rebooting? The question has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Didn't work with just a sudo before the command.

Run `sudo su -` then call `/path/to/dcicfg command=clearmemfailures`.